# Why does using parameter "autorun" of xRDP fail to connect to VNC server?

Tags: remote-desktop, xrdp

I am running Linux 4.4.48-2-ARCH #1 SMP Mon Feb 13 19:47:53 MST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux on a Raspberry Pi 3.

## Relevant installed applications

- xrdp
- tigervnc
- lightdm
- Xdmcp
- systemd

## Situation

### Working

1. LightDM is running without auto-seat enabled so that it can run in the background.
2. Login using Remote Desktop on Windows machine over port 3389 (default for rdp) by manually selecting "vnc-any" from the menu (`autorun=` is commented out in `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini`).
3. Connect to TigerVNC server over 5900 which is in multi-user mode using a systemd socket to start sessions per-login that use LightDM.

### Not Working

Same steps as above, except setting `autorun=xrdp4` in `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini` such that I can skip over the xrdp login menu.

```
[xrdp4]
name=vnc-any
lib=libvnc.so
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5900
username=na
password=na
```

## TigerVNC Configuration

/etc/systemd/system/xvnc.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=XVNC Server

[Socket]
ListenStream=5900
Accept=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

/etc/systemd/system/xvnc@service

```
[Unit]
Description=XVNC Server

[Socket]
ListenStream=5900
Accept=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
[root@archpi system]# cat xvnc@.service
[Unit]
Description=XVNC Per-Connection Daemon

[Service]
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/Xvnc -inetd -query localhost -once -SecurityTypes=None
User=nobody
StandardInput=socket
StandardError=syslog
```

## xRDP Log Output

```
[20170216-18:19:59] [INFO ] A connection received from: 10.18.0.57 port 58163
[20170216-18:19:59] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: 10.18.0.57:58163 - socket: 8
[20170216-18:19:59] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 7
[20170216-18:19:59] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 8
[20170216-18:19:59] [INFO ] A connection received from: 10.18.0.57 port 58164
[20170216-18:19:59] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: 10.18.0.57:58164 - socket: 8
[20170216-18:19:59] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 7
[20170216-18:19:59] [DEBUG] MCS_CJRQ - channel join request received
[20170216-18:20:00] [DEBUG] MCS_CJRQ - channel join request received
[20170216-18:20:00] [DEBUG] MCS_CJRQ - channel join request received
[20170216-18:20:00] [DEBUG] MCS_CJRQ - channel join request received
[20170216-18:20:00] [DEBUG] xrdp_0000065c_wm_login_mode_event_00000001
[20170216-18:20:00] [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x0407 found and dosen't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
[20170216-18:20:00] [INFO ] The following channel is allowed: rdpdr (0)
[20170216-18:20:00] [INFO ] The following channel is allowed: rdpsnd (1)
[20170216-18:20:00] [INFO ] The following channel is allowed: cliprdr (2)
[20170216-18:20:00] [INFO ] The following channel is allowed: drdynvc (3)
[20170216-18:20:00] [DEBUG] The allow channel list now initialized for this session
[20170216-18:20:00] [DEBUG] returnvalue from xrdp_mm_connect 0
[20170216-18:20:00] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: 10.18.0.57:58164 - socket: 8
[20170216-18:20:00] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20170216-18:20:00] [DEBUG] VNC mod_exit
[20170216-18:20:00] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: 127.0.0.1:5900 - socket: 11
```